# Open create content form modal and refresh view display in Drupal

Tags: drupal, refresh, modal-dialog, partial-page-refresh

I have a website developed using Drupal. What I want is to create a link which launches a modal window with a custom content create form, then when the form submits and the child window closes, a view or a display of a view in the parent must be refreshed.

I have tried using an excellent module like [automodal](http://drupal.org/project/automodal) and [ajax_views_refresh](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_views_refresh) but I can't get to set it right.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do this not so long ago, and while looking for a method to Preview content from the Modal Frame, came across your post. Hope this isn't to late to help.

Open parent.js under modules/modalframe/js

and insert `location.reload();` around line 250 within this if statement:

> `if ($.isFunction(self.options.onSubmit)) {
>         self.options.onSubmit(args, statusMessages);
>
>       }`

Now, when you click "Save" the child window closes and triggers a parent page refresh.